# Laravel whereNotExists relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, relationship

I have a few tables in database.
And I try create relation in `QuizSubmissionController` to get questions where haven't answered submission.
Can I write something like `$quiz_submission->quiz->questions()->whereDoesntHave('answers')` or `whereNotExist('submission_answers')`?
[image]

My relations here:

```
// Quiz Class
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

```
// Question Class
public function quiz()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Quiz::class);
}
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Category::class, Quiz::class);
}
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class,
        'question_id'
    );
}
```

```
// Answer Class
public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
}
```

```
// QuizSubmission Class
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function quiz()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Quiz::class);
}
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function questions()
{
    return $this->quiz()->whereNotExists()->questions();
}
public function submission_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubmissionAnswer::class);
}
public function getUnansweredQuestions()
{
    return $this->submission_answers()->doesntHave('answers');
}
```

```
// SubmissionAnswer Class
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
```

How to do `getUnansweredQuestions` to get all questions where not in `submission_answer` table? It's possible or I need to write raw database query?

I have also idea to insert all rows with questions ids without answer, and then get all `submission_answers` where `answer_id` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Laravel`, you can tweak relations to include conditions, so instead of trying to change the result as you tried. Create two relations, one with all answers, another one with the condition.

`Laravel` has `doesntHave()` and `orDoesntHave()`, for this logic you are trying to achieve. If you want this logic, with `SQL` conditions, you can use `whereDoesntHave()` that takes a closure with a query builder as input.

```
public function unansweredQuestions()
{
   return $this->hasMany(SubmissionAnswer::class)->doesntHave('answers');
}
```

Example to fetch `unansweredQuestions`.

```
$quizSubmission::find(42)->unansweredQuestions;
```

A bonus, what i consider clean code or high quality is consistency. Seing `submission_answers` as a relation name is not coherent with the naming convention. It should be public function `submissionAnswers()`.